# EPiServer - Cannot find add-on on installed ones

Tags: c#, nuget, episerver

I have created an add-on for EPiServer and I am trying to upload it on EpiServer. It shows that it is uploaded with success but when I navigate on the Installed Add-ons menu I cannot find it. Note that I upload it as nuget package (.nupkg). I attach two screenshots.

[image]

But it is not shown in the installed.
[image]

Comment: Which Episerver version is this?

Comment: It is 11.9.1. When I upload an external add-on it creates a folder of it at C:\EPiServer\Sites\EpiserverSite\EpiserverSite\App_Data\ModulesRepository but it does not happen with mine add-ons.

Comment: What does your `module.config` file look like for the addon?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<module>
    <assemblies>
     <!-- This adds the Alloy template assembly to the "default module" -->
        <add assembly="ExampleEpiserverSite" />
    </assemblies>
    <clientResources>
        <add name="epi-cms.widgets.base" path="Styles/Styles.css" resourceType="Style"/>
    </clientResources>
    <dojo>
        <!-- Add a mapping from alloy to ~/ClientResources/Scripts to the dojo loader configuration -->
        <paths>
            <add name="alloy" path="Scripts" />
        </paths>
    </dojo>
</module>

Comment: I reinstalled the site and now I am getting " 
There are assemblies installed with add-ons present in the main 'bin' directory. Please check the log for details."

Comment: You should probably not be developing addons that expects to be uploaded via the UI, it will be going away and it is expected that addons are installed via nuget packages in the solution and not through the UI

Comment: @ThomasSchmidt it may be a correct approach!